# Spring Boot does not recognize my JPA entity in a specific package

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, jpa, spring-data-jpa, entity

I am using Spring Boot and facing an issue with my JPA entity not being recognized as a managed type. I'd appreciate any help to solve this problem.

[**ERROR LOG**]

```
2023-10-08T23:13:04.005+02:00 ERROR 68 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication            : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'usersRepository' defined in com.vaadinapp.vaadinapp.repository.UsersRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on VaadinappApplication: Not a managed type: class com.vaadinapp.vaadinapp.model.Users at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1770) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
```

**[Project Structure:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IalYN.png)**

[**Entity: Users:**]

```
 package com.vaadinapp.vaadinapp.model;

import javax.persistence.*; import java.io.Serializable; import java.util.Objects;

@Entity @Table(name = "app_users") public class Users implements Serializable {


@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
private String username;

@Column(nullable = false)
private String password;

@Column(nullable = false)
private String email;

public Users() {
    // Default constructor for JPA
}

public Users(String username, String password, String email) {
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
    this.email = email;
}

// ... getters, setters, toString, hashCode, and equals methods
```

}

[*POM.XML*]

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"> <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion> <parent> <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId> <version>3.1.4</version> <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository --> </parent> <groupId>com.vaadinapp</groupId> <artifactId>vaadinapp</artifactId> <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version> <name>vaadinapp</name> <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description> <properties> <java.version>19</java.version> </properties>
```

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>vaadin-addons</id>
        <url>https://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.6.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    </dependency>



    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
                <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
        <artifactId>vaadin-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>24.1.11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

```
//[application.properties]

server.port=8081 logging.level.org.springframework=DEBUG spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/budgetwize_db spring.datasource.username=u_budgetwize spring.datasource.password=budgetwize2023@ spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL10Dialect spring.jpa.show-sql=true logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
```

I've checked the project structure, annotations, and dependencies, but I can't seem to find a solution. Any insights would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The error message "defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on: Not a managed type?" indicates that the class specified in the @EnableJpaRepositories annotation is not recognized as a managed type by the JPA framework.
ensure that the package containing the class is correctly scanned by the JPA configuration. You can do this by specifying the correct package(s) in the basePackages or basePackageClasses attribute of the **@EnableJpaRepositories** annotation.

Comment: I specified the packages in @EnableJpaRepositories but I still get the same error

Comment: did you set the repository path like this : @EnableJpaRepositories({"com.example.[path of your repo]"}) ?

Comment: yes but he doesn't work

Comment: spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization=true, set in application.properties